# Get UIView Height in UITableviewCell Autolayouts

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I want to get actual width of `UIViewA` according to device at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and 'UIViewA' is in custom `UITableViewCell`. I use AutoLayouts in `UITableViewCell`.

my UIViewA in in Custom UITableViewCell, UITableviewCell Width = 384
and My UITablVIewWidth = 284.
so I need UIViewA width is 284 at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Please guide me how can I get width of `UIView` at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because I want to add dynamic content in `UIView`.

Comment: It depends on where you want to get the height.

Comment: my UIViewA in in Custom UITableViewCell, UITableviewCell Width = 384
and My UITablVIewWidth = 284.
so I need UIViewA width is 284 at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: `view.superview.layoutIfNeeded()` and then get the height.

Comment: THanks @TheTiger but not working 
my UIViewA in in Custom UITableViewCell, UITableviewCell Width = 384 and My UITablVIewWidth = 284. so I need UIViewA width is 284 at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Your autolayouts are not set yet after that `cell.width` will be equal to `table.width` So `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` `tbl.reloadData()` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` `customCell.layoutIfNeeded()` then get the height.

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath 
(1) I set customCell.width is equal to Table width
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, self.tblLibrary.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];

(2) then called customCell.layoutIfNeeded()
and I get my desire width eqal to Table width
see my above code

but now problem is I can not expand my UIViewA height according to content wise Minimum Height Of UIVIewA is 64

I also set UIViewA cell.constViewAHeight.constant = intHeight

but not expanding height of UIView and same as Custome cell

Comment: You don't need to set cell width it will be automatically adjust in tableView,

Comment: Ya true its set automatically 
But When I am adding many UIButton with size 50 Programmatically in UIVIewA , according to UIViewA width 384 its added approximately 7 UIbuttons and the I have to add new UIButtons in new row 


I did this code but I got UIVIewA width is 383 at cellForRowAtIndexPath in every device and actually size of UIVIewA is 284
hence  6 and t7 UIButtons I can not see in each row

Comment: Use autolayout programmatically while adding buttons and cell height is autodimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169226/discussion-between-ankur-patel-and-thetiger).

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
cell.UIViewA.frame.size.width
```

or

```
cell.UIViewA.bounds
```

Comment: no I tried  I got size of storyboard.
I want to get size of device wise.
means if in IPhone 5, I got smaller size as compared to iPhone6s

Comment: in storyboard UIView width is 384 which is related to iPhone8

Now I want to get size regarding to iPhone5s and definitely in IPhone5 UIView width is less than 384

Comment: To get the device size:
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds
let width = screenSize.width
let height = screenSize.height

Comment: I do not want to need device size. I want to get UIView size according to device wise.

Comment: cell.UIViewA.frame.size.width this give me 384 in IPhone5 and 384 width is for iPhone8

Comment: Try bringing constraint outlets from storyboard to code? And check em.

Comment: Choose Assistant Editor (2 windows), 1. storyboard, the second one - automatic - VC, Command click the constraint in xxx VC Scene (storyboard list) and drag to VC. If you have any constraints ;)

Comment: oh ya I did it above thing.  According to requirements I also make constraints for height and width. I knew above this thing

Comment: means You want to say make width constraints of UIView and check that constraints Value.
am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought about

Comment: no bro its give same as storyboard width and that is 384

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your view creation in the cell

```
UIView *backgroundView = [UIView new];
[backgroundView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[self addSubview:backgroundView];


NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(backgroundView);


[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[backgroundView]|"
                                                                                options:0
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:viewsDictionary]];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[backgroundView]|"
                                                                                options:0
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Now you can print your view frame and get the width.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you need to consult a view's frame or bounds and it is positioned using Autolayout, first do the following:

```
[myView setNeedsLayout];
[myView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Now `myView` will have its correct frame and bounds.

Comment: my UIViewA in in Custom UITableViewCell, UITableviewCell Width = 384
and My UITablVIewWidth = 284.
so I need UIViewA width is 284 at cellForRowAtIndexPath 

I use your code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870952/get-uiview-height-in-uitableviewcell-autolayouts/49879574#49879574

but not working